# Drawrect improved text quality of my UILabels...Why?

Tags: ios, uilabel, drawrect

I had some trouble with my text quality suffering on all of my `UILabel`s in a few of my views. I have custom drawing on these views, each with several layers, and 5-10 `UILabel`s. The views overall are very similar just with a little different drawing.

The code was exactly the same for the `UILabel`s so I didn't understand why the text looked like crap on one of my views and not the other. Eventually I realized that I was calling `drawRect` in the class with the higher quality `UILabel`s.

I added a blank `drawRect` into the lower quality class and it immediately showed an improvement. Why is this, and is there a better way to improve the draw quality without the overhead of an empty `drawRect`?

Comment: I would suggest you perhaps go into more detail about what and how exactly you're drawing, perhaps with some code. It's going to be hard to give you more help without a better idea of where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: I removed all my custom drawing and only had the UILabels on the screen and the result was the same. The font is not an apple font though if this makes a difference.